# Create list with specific iteration in R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have the following dataset containing dates:

```
> dates
 [1] "20180412" "20180424" "20180506" "20180518" "20180530" "20180611" "20180623" "20180705" "20180717" "20180729"
```

I am trying to create a list where in each position, the name is 'Coherence_' + the first and second dates in `dates`. So in `output1[1]` I would have `Coherence_20180412_20180424`. Then in `output1[2]` I would have `Coherence_20180506_20180518`, etc.

I am starting with this code but it is not working they way I need:

```
output1<-list()
for (i in 1:5){
  output1[[i]]<-paste("-Poutput1=", S1_Out_Path,"Coherence_VV_TC", dates[[i]],"_", dates[[i+1]], ".tif", sep="")
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

M

Comment: `matrix(dates, 2)` and then use `apply(..., 2, ...)` over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Without loop

```
even_indexes<-seq(2,10,2) # List of even indexes
odd_indexes<-seq(1,10,2)  # List of odd indexes
print(paste('Coherence',paste(odd_indexes,even_indexes,sep = "_"),sep = "_"))
```

Link answer from here: [Create list in R with specific iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218824/create-list-in-r-with-specific-iteration?noredirect=1#comment91388316_52218824)

**Updated** **(To get data in List)**

```
lst=c(paste('Coherence',paste(odd_indexes,even_indexes,sep = "_"),sep = "_"))
```

**OR**

```
a=c(1:10)
for (i in seq(1, 9, 2)){
 print(paste('Coherence',paste(a[i],a[i+1],sep = "_"),sep = "_"))
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "Coherence_1_2"
[1] "Coherence_3_4"
[1] "Coherence_5_6"
[1] "Coherence_7_8"
[1] "Coherence_9_10"
```

Comment: How to save your result as a list where each output is in position `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create these patterns using `paste` capability to operate on vectors:

```
dates <- c("20180412", "20180424", "20180506", "20180518", "20180530", 
"20180611", "20180623", "20180705", "20180717", "20180729")
paste("Coherence", dates[1:length(dates)-1], dates[2:length(dates)], sep="_")
[1] "Coherence_20180412_20180424" "Coherence_20180424_20180506" "Coherence_20180506_20180518"
[4] "Coherence_20180518_20180530" "Coherence_20180530_20180611" "Coherence_20180611_20180623"
[7] "Coherence_20180623_20180705" "Coherence_20180705_20180717" "Coherence_20180717_20180729"
```

Or other simple patterns can be generated as:

```
paste("Coherence", dates[seq(1, length(dates), 2)], dates[seq(2, length(dates), 2)], sep="_")
[1] "Coherence_20180412_20180424" "Coherence_20180506_20180518" "Coherence_20180530_20180611"
[4] "Coherence_20180623_20180705" "Coherence_20180717_20180729"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matrix(..., nrow=2)`:

```
dates <- c("20180412", "20180424", "20180506", "20180518", "20180530", "20180611", "20180623", "20180705", "20180717", "20180729")
paste0("Coherence_", apply(matrix(dates, 2), 2, FUN=paste0, collapse="_"))
# > paste0("Coherence_", apply(matrix(dates, 2), 2, FUN=paste0, collapse="_"))
# [1] "Coherence_20180412_20180424" "Coherence_20180506_20180518" "Coherence_20180530_20180611" "Coherence_20180623_20180705"
# [5] "Coherence_20180717_20180729"
```